# What does a square bracket inside a join mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
mybin = b'abcdefghij'

a = ''.join([str(i) for i in mybin])  # Line 1
print (a)

a = ''.join(str(i) for i in mybin)    # Line 2
print (a)
```

Both print the same output. So what does the extra square bracket do in this case? And if it doesn't make a difference in this example, other are there other situations where this can make a difference?

Comment: `[str(i) for i in mybin]` is a list comprehension. `(str(i) for i in mybin)` is a generator expression. People tell me that it's faster to pass a list to `join` instead of a generator, but the effect is the same.

Comment: `[str(i) for i in mybin]` is a list comprehension meaning that it creates a list passed to join. `(str(i) for i in mybin)` is a generator expression meaning it creates a generator. The syntax allows to lose one set of brackets with the generator. It is equivalent to `.join((str(i) for i in mybin))`

Comment: See [Generator expressions vs. list comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47789/3890632)

Answer (score 0):

You can find it out using a debugger and if you assign the code in question to a variable:

```
mybin = b'abcdefghij'

line1 = [str(i) for i in mybin]
a = ''.join(line1)  # Line 1
print(a)

line2 = (str(i) for i in mybin)
a = ''.join(line2)  # Line 2
print(a)
```

`line1` is a list as a result from a list comprehension, `line2` creates a generator.

Screenshot from PyCharm:

[image: Debugger]